# How to check if every element of a list satisfies a condition inside an IF construct?

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have the list,

```
listx = {{0., -0.6}, {0.08, -1.}, {0.16, -0.9}, {0.24, 1.}, {0.32, 0.6}}
```

And I want to check if every second element satisfies both conditions ($ >= -1$ && $<= 1$).

I have tried my luck with AllTrue but I can't seem to make it work, this is what I have until now,

```
If[Do[AllTrue[listx, listx[[k, 2]] >= -1 && listx[[k, 2]] <= 1], {k, 1, 5, 1}], Print["a"]]
```

Care to help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you were on the right track, we can keep the code pretty similar to what you had and basically just remove the do loop:

```
If[AllTrue[listx, -1 <= #[[2]] <= 1 &], Print["a"]]
```

The `#[[2]]` specifies that it should test the second part of each element of `listx`. You could just use `#` there and replace `listx` with `listx[[All,2]]` as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

```
  If[SameQ @@ (-1 <= #2 <= 1 & @@@ listx), Print["true"],Print["false"]]
```

**Original Answer:**

```
 n = Length@listx; 
If[Total@Boole@Table[-1 <= listx[[k, 2]] <= 1, {k, n}] == n, Print["a"]]
```

Or

```
n = Length@listx; 
If[Total@Boole[-1 <= #2 <= 1 & @@@ listx] == n, Print["a"]] 

n = Length@listx;
If[Count[-1 <= #2 <= 1 & @@@ listx, True] == n, Print["a"]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna check it a little more and wait before marking it as solved, but I think you solved it!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Do` loop does not return a `True`, so the clause in your `If` statement never evaluates.

```
hasValidSecondElement[{_, x_}] := x >= -1 && x <= 1
hasValidSecondElement[___] := False

AllTrue[listx, hasValidSecondElement]
(* True *)
```

I defined a helper function for readability.  When you go back to this code, it is clear what the intention was for a line like `AllTrue[listx, hasValidSecondElement]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Thread` allows for a really nice syntax here:

```
If[And @@ Thread[-1 <= listx[[All,2]] <= 1], Print["a"]]
```